# Webpack truncating output

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm getting a weird error where it appears webpack is truncating my JS bundle. I get:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

If you look at this screenshot, you'll notice there's a call to a `ispose()` function on line 3865. I believe that is supposed to be a call to `dispose`, hence why I think this output is being truncated.

[image]

I'm not sure what the cause of this might be, but I wanted to see if anyone else has seen this before. Every now and then, when I rebuild my solution, the JS bundle is fixed, but is then broken again after another rebuild.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try running webpack validator? It sounds like there might be an error/typo in your webpack config

Comment: I didn't. I suspected it might be because I have a npm script that starts a Express server and starts watching Webpack changes. I decoupled that script into two separate npm commands and I have not run into this issue again.